# Does rsyslog forward comments(#)?

Tags: unix, logging, rsyslog

I'm forwarding many files to the syslog server using rsyslog in my Ubuntu Machine.
I'm adding the files one by one to the rsyslog.conf file and I'm using the imfile module to forward the logs to the syslog server.

Some log files have comments i.e., some lines in the log files begin with #.

I remember that earlier those lines were not forwarded to the syslog(I do not remember the version of rsyslog)

Now I checked in rsyslog v7.4 and rsyslog v8.38. The commented lines are also forwarded.

I want to know if the commented lines will be forwarded in all versions of rsylog and will it be forwarded in all Unix machines?

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on how you configure rsyslog, you could configure it with a rule to drop messages which start with the # character, or you could forward them. If you give examples of the config from each setup I could probably tell you which part is dropping the messages if that is configured.